# How to capture the screen in a Metro C# app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Anyone got a snip for grabbing a screenshot of your metro app using C#? Or C++? Or VB?

Thanks...

Answer (score 6):

> No, there is no way for a Metro style app to do this. By design they cannot directly interact with other apps outside of themselves, including capturing screenshots which may include other apps.
>   There also isn't a way for a Metro style app to render Xaml elements to a bitmap so you can't readily implement this for your own app.
>   --Rob

More details are found here : [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/63dd9596-bf94-440b-847a-961cbf036e7b/)

I haven't test this solution but it might work if you try to let your app press the Window Key + PrintScreen and it should put the picture into the Pictures folder from there you can access the picture through Windows Integration (I think)

Comment: Indeed. You can't take a screen shot programmatically from the app. The normal methods that a user would take a screen shot are still available, as is the knew touch specific win+another button I can't remember. That, and the "Take picture" button in the simulator.

Comment: not looking for the 'keyboard' ways.  definitely looking for programmatic.  what about just capturing the current programs window and saving it to a picture or local file?

Comment: As Rob said, it's impossible for the Metro Style Apps to do this, It's a different FCL that it is using unlike WPF, WinForms or Silverlight. So capturing the current program window might just give you the picture of the desktop and not the metro start screen/app.