# not able to take screenshot with copyfromscreen which is not supported in visualstudio 2012 c# express for windows8

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot using c# for windows8 in visual studio 2012 express.Api copyfromscreen is not supported in windows8.Is there any other way to take a screenshot programmatically using c# for windows8.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same question as this one?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779095/how-to-capture-the-screen-in-a-metro-c-sharp-app

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: it can't be done.

More specifically, Microsoft have specifically restricted the ability of a Metro app to take screenshots, either of themselves or other applications.  Desktop applications are still able to access the various methods for taking screenshots, but Metro apps may not.  This is by design, and apparently not likely to change.

More information on this can be found in [this post on the MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/63dd9596-bf94-440b-847a-961cbf036e7b/). (Linked from Stack Overflow question [How to capture the screen in a Metro C# app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779095/how-to-capture-the-screen-in-a-metro-c-sharp-app) as mentioned by Olav's comment)

Comment: Thankyou @Corey for clarifying the doubt.

Comment: For the love of all things sacred, give him an upvote or mark his answer as the answer to give him credit.